# How to show that this sum is zero, $\sum^{k}_{j=0}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!(k-j)!} $ whenever $k \ge 1$?

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

Is there a simple way to prove this sum,
$$S_{k} =\sum^{k}_{j=0}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j!(k-j)!}~ ,$$
is zero whenever $k \ge 1$? Whenever $k$ is odd, I know I can pair up the terms and it cancels out, but I'm not sure to do whenever $k$ is even.

Comment: What is the binomial expansion of $(1-1)^k$?

Comment: @Henry, wow so easy. Thanks.